# TFS Wrong file encoding coming from git

Tags: tfs

I've been doing some tests, taking my code from git to TFS, using git-tf. Everything worked pretty much ok, except TFS thinks almost all my files are binary (discovered while finding the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37590731/385646)). Actually, all UTF8 or UTF16 files are detected correctly, but those with an unspecified encoding (.cpp and .h files, mostly) are detected as binary.

Is there a way (some setting, or anything else) to convert from git to TFS and keep the correct encoding? Or, probably less ideal, to change the encoding of all the wrongly encoded ones in TFS?

Answer (score 0):

If you have not set the type of a file, Git will determine it automatically and may treat as binary. With the [.gitattributes](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) file you can override its decision.

Tyr to add the diff attribute in the .gitattributes file:

```
*.cpp -diff
*.h -diff
```

Comment: But does this affect how TFS decides whether a file is binary or text?

Comment: No. If you want to mark a file as binary, just unset the diff attribute in the .gitattributes file. You can refer to gitattributes file for more information: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes

Comment: I don't want to mark files as binary. My problem is that TFS has decided that pretty much all my files are binary, when they are text files. This has happened with some tests I've been doing, but when I really move my repository to TFS I would like to my files correctly detected. Otherwise things like merge don't work.

Comment: Git may determine the file with really long lines or with some wide characters as binary. To get rid of it, add the diff attribute in the .gitattributes file.